# Mandar mensaje a través de un paquete UDP con netcat?

Tags: linux, bash, redes

Holaa, he intentado mandar mensaje de mi máquina A a una B pertenecientes a la misma red, pero no he tenido Éxito.

La idea es que este mensaje sea del estilo de una alerta.

Corriendo en la maquina B:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
        nc -v  -l -u -p 9999  
done
```

y en la maquina A para mandar el mensaje `echo "Hola" | nc -u IP_B 9999`
pero al parecer no funciona, mando un mensaje pero luego el listener aunque le vuelva a mandar algo no recibe nada nuevo, ademas mi idea es que B este siempre escuchando y procese lo que le llega y A mande un mensaje y se cierre la conexion por parte de el, mediante script , no usando ctrl+c . Es decir los mensajes solo iran en una direccion. y A mandara un mensaje solo cada x tiempo, si tener el canal abierto dado que estara haciendo otras tareas.+

Pd: tambien en A he usado `echo "hola" >/dev/udp/La ip de b/9999`

Si conoceis otro comando que me sirva utilizando UDP , me serviria.
Por ejemplo si se pudiese mandar a la otra maquina un mensaje del estilo del comando `wall`

**Como ultima aclaracion, el objectivo de eso es que se mande A mande a B una alerta de por ejemplo "C se ha caido", B procese esa alerta y tome acciones, pero aun asi siga escuchando por si hay alguna otra alerta de A.**

**A termina su conexion pero B sigue escuchando , futuramente A tendria que mandar otra alerta B**

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: La solución va en.a zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta, quitala de ahí por favor y pública donde corresponde

Answer (score 0):

Revisa qué servicio tienes corriendo en dichos puertos con alguno de estos:

```
$ sudo lsof -i UDP:9999 # O simplemente -i UDP
$ sudo netstat -ulpn
$ sudo ss -ulp
```

Si están corriendo, trata de ver en qué dirección IP, ya que una cosa es que cora en localhost (127.0.0.1) y el servicio sólo será accesible dentro de tu máquina, otra es que corra en tu ip local (e.g. 192.168.1.111), y otra es que corra por defecto en todas las interfaces disponibles (0.0.0.0).

Trata de abrir dos sesiones en ese mismo servidor y ejecutar un simple chat.

Supón que sabes la ip local de tu máquina porque la viste con `ip addr | grep -E "inet 192"`. Esto te dará como resultado direcciones de la forma 192.etc., pero tu puedes quitar el 192 para ver todas las disponibles en caso de que no tengan ese prefijo.

Una vez copiando una de las direcciones que quieras (yo te recomiendo la local, es decir, por ejemplo, 192.168.1.123), haz esto en los dos usuarios:

```
usuario1$ nc -ul <una dirección que elegiste> 9999
usuario2$ nc -u <la dirección que elegiste> 9999
```

Y deberías poder chatear entre usuarios. Si no es así, revisa las reglas del firewall. Puedse utilizar `iptables` para eso:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
```

Y a sí, revisas en tu computadora corriendo el servicio, si hay alguna restricción para tal dirección, puerto, etc.

**Nota**: utilizo la versión de netcat de openbsd, no la tradicional. Esto puede hacer que el comando de `nc` varía por una letra o dos.

Comment: Hola, primero quiero agradecerte que hayas invertido tu tiempo en una respuesta tan extensa, despues de esto , quiero decirte que despues de usar por ejemplo ```ss -ulp``` el puerto esta disponible para todas las ifaces(0.0.0.0) , por otro lado, me has respondido a como crear un chat, pero lo que ncesito es enviar 1 paquete UDP con una mensaje y que lo reciba el listener en otra maquina, y que el que manda termine esa conexion pero que el listener continue funcionando por si en un futuro , esa misma maquina vuelve a madar al listener otro mensaje.
Lo explico mejor en mi ultima aclaracion.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar la opcion -k de NetCat en la parte del listener

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
        nc  -l -k -u -p 9999  
done
```